# Bad smell coming from bathroom sink-cold water only

Tags: plumbing

We have a two-story home with three bathrooms and in our hallway bath that hardly ever gets used, we have two sinks. Whenever we turn on the cold water in either sink, we get a sewer smell for about two or three seconds. It only happens in that bathroom and we have filled a glass of water and walked away and it’s not the water that smells. I have poured every kind of solution that you can think of down the drain and overflow and I’m still getting the smell. I had a plumber come out and check the P-trap and he said that it was fine and that he could not figure out what it could be. We are not experiencing this in any of our other bathrooms or kitchen. The only thing I can think of is that bathroom is closest to a huge tree we have out front and possibly the roots have been penetrated into the sewer line and creating a smell. Any, suggestions or ideas would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Roots in a sewer line gives bigger problems than smell.  Just wondering if the p-trap might start drying out if hardy used, but that might happen if it is once a month.  Cleaning drains/over flows is harder than just dumping stuff down them.

Comment: I even went to Home Depot and bought a pipe brush and tried to clean both drains, but nothing really showed up as any type of gunk or debris. Any suggestions cleaning on the drain/overflows other than with a brush?

Comment: If you flow the water into a bowl (instead of the drain) do you get the smell?

Comment: plug the drain and the overflow ... run water ... do you still smell the odor?

Comment: I just put a bowl in the sink and turned the cold water on and the smell is still there, but went away after a few seconds.

Comment: All this time I thought the smell was coming from the drain but now I’m wondering if it’s from the supply line. Maybe the flexible hose iunder the sink. I tried filling a glass of water and walking away and smelling it and the water doesn’t smell so I’m not sure what’s going on.

Comment: Since it is not the drain that is causing the smell, I believe it is in the cold water supply lines.